# How to insert long value in mongo using node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to insert Long value for an attribute in mongo.

```
  var sequences = this.db.collection('sequences');
  sequences.insert( {
      _id: "TEST_SEQ",
      value: 1
  }, done);
```

But this is inserting value as integer, how to make it Long?

Comment: Can you please mark the correct answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use mongodb `Long` class. Something like this.

```
const Long = require('mongodb').Long;

var sequences = this.db.collection('sequences');
sequences.insert( {
    _id: "TEST_SEQ",
    value: Long.fromInt(1)
}, done);
```

Take a look [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html#long-fromint) for more details

Mongo-db has default types it gives values, That's why it's inserted as an integer.

Answer (score 5):

Use the NumberLong constructor:

```
sequences.insert({ "value" : NumberLong(322) }, cb)
```

Comment: Which require statement is needed?