# Cannot xor mongodb field from nodejs without mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to xor the field `status`, in a document such as this:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c51e1aedb6e4000410ddbf"),
    "query" : "developer",
    "user_id" : "1413322622039651",
    "status" : 1,
    "links" : [
        "840673302343483394",
        "840672745222483968",
        "840672580717686785",
        "840672427550089216",
        "840582170548850688",
        "840581988918669312"
    ],
    "links_size" : 6,
    "created" : ISODate("2017-03-12T10:08:26.369Z")
}
```

I'm using this code:

```js
var args = {'_id': new ObjectID(queryId)};
var bit = {$bit: {'status': {xor: 1}}};
db.collection('query').update(args, bit, function(err, result) {});
```

The query produces no error but the field `status` is not changed. I think that the problem is that it interprets 1 as a double not as a integer. I tried: `parseInt(1)` but it also had no effect. I tried to use `NumberInt(1)` but got the error `NumberInt is not defined`.

So I can't make it work in my code; however, the equivalent query through the mongo shell works as expected:

```js
db.query.update(
  {"_id":ObjectId("58c3b98e458f0700045b1846")}, 
  {"$bit":{"status":{"xor":NumberInt(1)}}}
)
```

I googled and found that `NumberInt` is present in the *mongoose-int32* package but it requires mongoose. I don't want to add mongoose as a dependency for my project so I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: Hey, just tested with bard native driver and with Mongoose. It works for me: http://jsbin.com/canicalexo/1/edit?js I'm at: Node.js 6.9.1, Mongoose: 4.8.7, MongoDB: 3.4.2. Could you try running my snippets, also what version do you use?

Comment: @AntonioNarkevich please note that i don't use mongoose

Comment: The first snippet works without mongoose. 'mongodb' package is 2.2.24

Comment: that spinnet is exactly as my code that doesn't work. 'mongodb' package has the same version

Comment: node-mongodb-native provides a Long implementation, maybe you can use that to workaround your isse. According to the docs either `NumberLong` or `NumberInt` can be used with `$bit`. 
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/bit/#up._S_bit 
See: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/long.html#long-fromint
Similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27167569/987860

Comment: @Ben again `NumberLong is not defined`...

Comment: @rocknow See the linked question. Use with `const Long = require('mongodb').Long;` and then `Long.fromInt(1)` as your xor value.

Comment: @Ben thanks, I tried. Result is the same as initial: no error but the field is not changed.

Comment: can you post the output of `db.query.find({{"_id":ObjectId("58c3b98e458f0700045b1846")})` ?

Comment: Could be an issue with your data type for `status` in your existing doc.

Comment: @felix i've edited my question and added an example of the document. The document with original id isn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the `status` field type stored in your document

here it is

`{ "status" : 1, ... }`

but you should have this:

`{ "status" : NumberLong(1), ... }`

First, convert all status field to NumberLong using this code (run it directly in the shell)

```
db.query.find().forEach( function(obj) {
    obj.status = new NumberLong(obj.status);
    db.query.save(obj);
});
```

then just update your previous code like this :

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId
const Long = require('mongodb').Long

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database', function (err, db) {
  if (err != null) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    let args = {'_id': new ObjectId('58c64231b13b6239d9e496da')}
    let bit = {$bit: {'status': {xor: Long.fromInt(1)}}}

    db.collection('query').update(args, bit, function (err, result) {
      if (err != null) {
        console.error(err)
      }
      db.close()
    })
  }
})
```

This worked using:

- node v**7.3.0**
- npm package mongodb **2.2.24**
- MongoDB **3.4.1**

Comment: the same result, it doesn't work. have you tried it by yourself?

Comment: @rocknow see my edit. It works fine for me, does it prompt any errors?

Comment: `var args = {'_id': new ObjectID(queryId)};
 var bit = {$bit: {'status': {xor: Long.fromInt(1)}}};
 console.log("database: query.update(%s, %s)", JSON.stringify(args), JSON.stringify(bit));`
ouput:  

`database: query.update({"_id":"58c6a5aca1a01b00043b2f3f"}, {"$bit":{"status":{"xor":"1"}}})`

i'm confused by "1"...

Comment: @rocknow this is strange... Are the status fields correctly updated after the NumberLong conversion step using `db.query.find().forEach( function(obj) {
    obj.status = new NumberLong(obj.status);
    db.query.save(obj);
});` ?

Comment: @rocknow can you add the expected output for samples documents that aren't currently updated correctly ?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you. what do you want me to add?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137993/discussion-between-felix-and-rocknow).